# xboxdrv is not working on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: connection, 17.10, xbox-one

I'm trying to connect my Xbox one wireless controller to my ThinkPad t430s. When I try to run systemctl enable I get Unit xboxdrv.service not found. I've tried manually downloading and enabling it and creating a new service file but to no avail. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you should to start `xboxdrv` as a service. Instead, just type from a terminal

```
sudo xboxdrv
```

and you should be able to  test it.
You may need to run

```
sudo rmmod xpad
```

first.

When you want to use it for gaming, mind that you run

```
sudo xboxdrv --silent
```

instead, as printing the events to a terminal hogs a lot of CPU.

---

Note on what you were trying to do: I have `xboxdrv` successfully installed, but running

```
systemctl enable xboxdrv.service
```

gives me

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file xboxdrv.service does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but it's a little ugly... The package must be broken because it does not install the src files.

[This one goes in /lib/systemd/system/](https://github.com/raelgc/ubuntu_xboxdrv/blob/master/src/lib/systemd/system/xboxdrv.service)

before trying to start the service you may need to do the same to all the files in the src directory from the link above. Careful to follow the path.
src/etc goes into /etc src/usr/share goes into /usr/share and so forth.

Then run :
`sudo systemctl daemon reload
sudo rmmod xpad
sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service
sudo systemctl start xboxdrv`

after some people needed to install a patch and dkms

```
`sudo apt install dkms`
```

[steamos-dkms-patch](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeslaur/steamos/ubuntu/pool/main/s/steamos-xpad-dkms/)

download and dpkg -i the file
good luck